# javascript not passing parameters to rails application

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

The following snippet of javascript

```
          if (result) {
            console.log(result)
            document.getElementById('result').textContent = result.text
let formData = new FormData();
let CodeParams = {
  code_data: result.text,
  user_id: <%= current_user.id %>
};
formData.append("code_json_data", JSON.stringify(CodeParams));
Rails.ajax({
  url: "security_check",
  type: "get",
  data: formData
  });
```

is generating the following console.log entry:

```
{text: "1589006144;211;337322133467", rawBytes: Uint8Array(36), numBits: 288, resultPoints: Array(4), format: 11, …}
```

and the div on the page is beign refreshed with `result.text` as expected.
but when the get action is launched, the following is being submitted to the server:

```
/security_check?[object%20FormData]
```

why are the parameters not being generated, when the log entry is as expected?

Comment: a `FormData` instance is not serializable to a string directly for query params on a GET request

Comment: Right.  but when I change it to `post` the URL is simply `/security_check `

Comment: if you change it to post, the data is sent in the request body instead of in the URL. If you need to send it in the URL, you can do `data = "code_json_data=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(CodeParams))` then send that string directly as the data

Comment: Got it!  Got both ways working.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to send the data as a `GET` request, you'll need to convert the data to a string rather than using `FormData`. The `Rails.ajax` method for `GET` requests just treats the `data` option as a string, and `formData.toString()` would be `[object FormData]`.

```js
let CodeParams = {
  code_data: result.text,
  user_id: <%= current_user.id %>
};

Rails.ajax({
  url: "security_check",
  type: "get",
  data: 'code_json_data=' + encodeURIComponent(CodeParams)
});
```